# Kotlin Spring Boot Project - generate .d.ts files for DTO objects for client distribution

Tags: javascript, java, typescript, kotlin

I'm using Kotlin & Spring Boot (with gradle) and have a few DTO `data` classes in Kotlin that I'd like to produce a .d.ts file from when I build my webapp.

I really don't have anything special in my Gradle file, it's the standard Kotlin -> Spring Boot gradle from initilzr

Everything I can find talks about Javascript specific projects, but I'd like to be able to generate .d.ts files for my DTOs so I don't have to manually maintain the definitions in the javascript client(s)

Any ideas on doing this?

Comment: https://blog.jetbrains.com/kotlin/2020/03/kotlin-1-4-m1-released/#exporting-declarations-to-javascript

Comment: Does this really have a good reason to have the [tag:java] and [tag:javascript] tags?

Comment: @rainbow.gekota - Yes.